# Sas Check if array/list contains element

Tags: sas

My problem is the following.

I have a list of elements

```
("first element", "segundo elemento", "hirugarrena", "fourth element")
```

And lets say I have a separate element that says `"h"`

I have tried to find a way to check if there is any of the elements in the list contain that lonely element (h), so that the `contains` turns to be `true`

Something like `if (list contains (h)) THEN output possible_element;`

I have tried to do some silly combinations with `=*` and `in` but all I get is a sintax error.

In sum, I have been trying to find something like `if/where element sounds like in list.`

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your desired result here?  Do you want `hirugarrena` to match `h` here?  Where is the list of elements - is it a dataset?

Comment: Say I have two sets of elements, and say the first one is ingredients, and the second is recipes. I would like to find a way to find if a recipe contains an ingredient

Comment: Please post some sample code to show how your datasets appear and what your desired result is.

Comment: I will post some sample code tomorrow, thanks in advance guys, most appreciated!!

Comment: Another option depending on data structure is the whichc function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather I think that you may want the following:

```
For i = LBound(elements) To HBound(elements)
    If Find(elements{i},"h") > 0 Then
       do;
       /*do stuff*/
    End;
Next;
```

You can use the find function which would give you the character count of your search criteria and then just apply it to some logic.

In the above example you just need to replace 'h' with your search criteria.

Comment: It's unclear to me if this answers the question or not, because the question isn't sufficiently clear, but the concept is good.  You do need to add a `do;` to your `if` given you supplied the `end;` though.

Comment: Good point... I'm used to using a slightly modified version of SAS in an API and it doesn't require the do;

Comment: `do;` isn't required if you're just running one statement, but the `end` would be out of place without the `do`.  (Unless your API is reading your indenting/linefeeds and adding it for you?)

Answer (score 3):

If your elements are in an array, then you can use the `in` operator, for example:

```
data _null_;

  array elements(*) $20 e1-e4
      ('first element','segundo elemento','hirugarrena','fourth element');

  h = 'fourth element';

  if h in elements then do; /* USE THE IN OPERATOR TO TEST FOR A MATCH */
    put 'found';
  end;
  else do;
    put 'not found';
  end;

run;
```

Edit: Sorry -- I typed "if" instead of "in" in my explanation.  Unfortunate typo, now corrected.

Comment: Alright, lets say I have a list of 90 elements. I am supposed to write one by one? I have seen in forums that people tend to use cards.

Comment: `if` is a statement, not an operator.  `in` is the operator of interest here.

Comment: @Mayhem You need to specify more details in the question.  How do you have this list of 90 elements now?  Is it 90 variables in a dataset?  Is it one variable in a dataset with 90 rows?  If you don't have it in a dataset, you either need to put it in a dataset or you need to type it out somewhere...